# How to Catch errors thrown by a Widget

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, widget

I'm using 3rd party library [Cached network image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image), sometime it throws network errors, given these errors are thrown by a widget, asynchronously, how can I catch them?

or in general, if a 3rd party widget throws an exception, is there a way to catch it?

Answer (score 0):

In `CachedNetworkImage`, you will get a callback `errorWidget` which will be returned only when a network error occurs or the URL is incorrect. You can return any widget that you want when the error occurs.

You cannot catch an error in `CachedNetworkImage`.

You can use `Connectivity` package to check for network related issues:
[Link](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity)

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using `errorWidget` but some network errors are still thrown!

Comment: You can use `Connectivity` package for additional network-related errors. I have updated the answer also.

Comment: OK, I'm also using Connectivity, this is a weird network issue that can happen, anyway the question still stands, if a 3rd party widget throws an error internally, is there a way to catch it?